# Trying to create a channel for a specific category_ID

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
else if (commandName === "team") {
    const teamName = options.getString("name");
    let teamChannelName = teamName
      .toLowerCase()
      .replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, "-")
      .substring(0, 100);

    try {
      // Check if team already exists
      const existingTeam = await Team.findOne({ name: teamName });
      if (existingTeam) {
        return await interaction.reply({ content: "Team already exists." });
      } else {
        // Create the team in the database
        const createdTeam = await Team.create({ name: teamName });

        // Add the team creator to the team
        const user = await User.findOne({ discordId: interaction.user.id });
        createdTeam.members.push(user);
        await createdTeam.save();

        // Get the team category
        const teamCategory =
          interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(TEAM_CATEGORY_ID);
        if (!teamCategory || teamCategory.type !== "category") {
          console.error("Team category not found or invalid.");
          return await interaction.reply({
            content: "Team category not found or invalid.",
          });
        }

        // Print out the generated channel name for debugging
        console.log("Generated Channel Name:", teamChannelName);
        console.log("Generated Team Cat Name:", teamCategory);
        // Create the team channel
        const teamChannel = await interaction.guild.channels.create(
          teamChannelName,
          {
            type: "text",
            parent: teamCategory,
            permissionOverwrites: [
              {
                id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
              },
            ],
          },
        );

        await interaction.reply({ content: "Team created successfully!" });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating team:", error);
      await interaction.reply({ content: "Failed to create team." });
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to create a team channel so that when a user uses the team (team name), a channel is automatically created under that `TEAM_CATEGORY_ID` (which is taken from Discord). But I can't seem to add people to the `team` and the `channel` is not created, instead it says team category **not found** or **invalid**.

I've tried the code a bit with different approaches, please let me have a hand in this by the way its a text channel not having a voice

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).